# Convert WrappedArray into an iterable in Scala

Tags: scala

There is a Spark DF with schema -

```
root
|-- array_name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- string_element string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- double_element: double (nullable = true)
```

For a row of the df -

Results in an array of values that look like the following, where each index is another array of 2 items (of type String and Double, respectively), however, the type is Any instead of WrappedArray

```
val wrappedArray = row.get(0)
 [WrappedArray([2020-08-01,3.1109513062027883E7], [2020-09-01,2.975389347485656E7], [2020-10-01,3.0935205531489465E7], ...]
```

The end goal is to convert this into a Map where the String is the key and the Double (converted to Int) is the value

Final variable should look like this -

```
val finalMap: Map[String, Int] = Map("2020-08-01" -> 31109513, "2020-09-01" -> 29753893, "2020-10-01" -> 30935205, ...)
```

The main issue is, Spark returns an `Any` object, so the wrappedArray's compile time type is actually non-iterable, I just want to be able to loop through wrappedArray, which Any is not allowing.

Comment: You cannot cast it into an immutable list, because it's a mutable collection. What are you trying to achieve in the first place? `collection.mutable.WrappedArray(("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)).toMap` works just fine, and produces `Map(a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3)`.

Comment: In addition to @AndreyTyukin 's comment, if the internal things inside your wrapped array are not tuples, and are arrays, you can just convert them to tuples, and then use `.toMap`. `wrappedArray.collect { case Array(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap`

Comment: I'm using Scala 2.11 and I don't get any of the functions, either toMap or collect as options to apply on the wrappedArray object, giving error: `error: value collect is not a member of Any`

Comment: `Any` is definitely not a subtype of `WrappedArray`. Either it's not an array, or you're somehow losing the type elsewhere. Your problem is elsewhere entirely.